# Paypal : How do I get Paypal to redirect back to my site?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to create a 'buy now' button for Paypal.

Here is the process :

1. Visitor fills out a form on my site with info such as name, email
2. Visitor clicks 'buy now'
3. Visitor visits Paypal, places payment
4. Either Visitor is redirected back to my site
5. I am emailed with my visitor's information

My questions :

1. How do I pass these custom fields to Paypal? I'm happy with a "Buy now" button.
2. How do I get Paypal to redirect back to me after purchase?
3. How do I get Paypal to pass those custom fields to my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have started creating your button, click on Step 3: Customize advanced features.
Then put a check mark in the spot that says "Take Customers to this URL when Finished"

Once you enter your URL and save your button your customers will be redirected at the end of checkout.

Below is the screen shot from PayPal.

[image: Step Three]

Answer (score 0):

Sign into your PayPal account and then go to Merchant Services --> Create Payment Buttons for your Website.

Click on the icon under the Guides for the Buy Now button and it has step by step instructions on what to do.

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/buy-now-button

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I have already created a button. What I don't know is how to pass arbitrary custom fields and how to get Paypal to pass those fields back to a page of my choice. How do I do that?